# Using the enumerate function with sub-string/similar strings

Tags: python-3.x, list, substring, list-comprehension, enumerate

Attempting to find the index of strings in two lists. Having a problem because the strings are similar.

```
 directories = ['C:/Desktop/5SvF9yM6ldXGRpBz1.csv',
'C:/Desktop/5SvF9yM6ldXGRpBz11.csv',
'C:/Desktop/5SvF9yM6ldXGRpBz12.csv']

 barcodes = ['5SvF9yM6ldXGRpBz1',
'5SvF9yM6ldXGRpBz11',
'5SvF9yM6ldXGRpBz12']
```

The output below. How do I get the first barcode '5SvF9yM6ldXGRpBz1' = [0] instead of [0,1,2]

```
5SvF9yM6ldXGRpBz1
[0, 1, 2]
5SvF9yM6ldXGRpBz11
[1]
5SvF9yM6ldXGRpBz12
[2]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should consider the following

```
from os.path import basename, splitext
[[i for k in barcodes if k==splitext(basename(j))[0]] for i,j in enumerate(directories)]

[[0], [1], [2]]
```

or you can use regular expression:

```
import re
[[i for k in barcodes if re.sub('.*/(\w+).*','\\1',j)==k] for i,j in enumerate(directories)]
[[0], [1], [2]]
[[i for k in barcodes if re.sub('.*/|\\..*','',j)==k] for i,j in enumerate(directories)]
[[0], [1], [2]]
```

Comment: @Onyambu....thanks for your help again. This is not quite what I had in mind. Each barcode show point to a single index. What I'm looking for is.    
5SvF9yM6ldXGRpBz1
[0]
5SvF9yM6ldXGRpBz11
[1]
5SvF9yM6ldXGRpBz12
[2]

Comment: It seems like the function is confused with '5SvF9yM6ldXGRpBz1' because it's a substring of the other two barcodes. Only difference is the other two barcodes end in ''11" and "12"

Comment: you could create a dictionary or a tuple: eg `{j:[i for k in directories if j==splitext(basename(k))[0]] for i,j in enumerate(barcodes)}`

Comment: @defjamvan. Exactly. That is the issue. To go around that, you will have to use regular expressions or even `==`

Comment: I won't be able to use  == since it is checking to see if barcodes is in directories. : barcode_index = [i for i,x in enumerate(directories) if unique_b_code == x] don't work as you suggested.

Comment: @defjamvan check on how i managed to use `==` or even `{j:[i for k in directories if re.search(f'{j}\\.',k)] for i,j in enumerate(barcodes)}`

Comment: In your example to create a dictionary or tuple?

Comment: @defjamvan yes. Probably I have enumerated the wrong side. Check out this `{k:[i for i,j in enumerate(directories) if re.search(f'{k}\\.',j)] for k in barcodes}`

Comment: Ahh. I see what you mean. From there I can iterate over the dict to get the indexes, correct?

Comment: @defjamvan. you can just call the `list(dic.values())` and it will give you the indices, you do not need to do any iterations. But its your call. You can do all that you desire. Everything is at your disposal

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209111/discussion-between-defjamvan-and-onyambu).